# A similar proposition to Riesz's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, $\{u_k\}$ is a non precompact sequence with $\|u_k\|=1$ , then there exists a subsequence $\{v_k=u_{n_k}\}$ and a constant $a>0$ such that
>   $$d(v_k,\mathrm{span}\{v_1,\cdots,v_{k-1}\})>a$$

I think it's similar to Riesz's lemma, but I do not have idea to use the condition 'non precompact', any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check the assumptions are written correctly. As written the result is false. For example, let $H = \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the sequence $u_n = (n^{-\frac12}, (1-n^{-1})^\frac12)$. Then $\|u_n\| = 1$ and $u_n \to (0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$. Additionally the sequence $\{u_n\}$ is non-compact since $(0,1) \not \in \{u_k: k \geq 1\}$ and so the sequence is not sequentially compact. 

However, $\operatorname{span}\{u_i,u_j\} = H$ whenever $i \neq j$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you! I think the assumptions are correct now.

Comment: This still isn't quite right. If $u_k$ is a constant sequence then $\{u_k: k \geq 1\}$ has no limit point (since $x$ is a limit point of $S$ iff whenever $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, $S \cap U \setminus \{x\} \neq \emptyset$). If you want an assumption similar to non-compactness that excludes my counterexample then maybe assuming that $\{u_k: k \geq 1\}$ is not relatively compact is right. I'm not sure if the result is true with this assumption but I can't think of an obvious counterexample. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @RhysSteele It's homework from my teacher written by hand... He writes 'noncompactness', I think what does he mean is 'not relatively compact'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need that space $H$ is separable (it is obvious since your statement is about sequence $\{u_n\}$ that belongs to a subspace $H_0 = \overline{Span \{u_n\}}$ and $H_0$ is a separable Hilbert space). So I will not use this assumption (that was a note that explains why this assumption is not necessary).

Next we observe that if a metric space $X$ is not precompact (I suppose that precompact is a synonym for totally bounded) then you can construct a number $\alpha_0 > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \in X$ such that $d(x_n, x_m) > \alpha_0$ for all $n \ne m$. So we choose a subsequence $w_k = u_{n_k}$ such that $||w_n - w_m|| > \alpha_0$ for some $\alpha_0 > 0$ and $n \ne m$.

Now we construct a sequence $v_k = w_{m_k}$ by induction for arbitrary $a < \frac{\alpha_0}{2}$. $v_1$ is set to be $w_1$. Next, assume that we have already constructed $v_1, \dots, v_k$. If you can't make a choice then for all $m > m_k$ you have $d(w_m, Span\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}) \le a = \frac{\alpha_0}{2}$. Let $w_m = h_m + r_m$ where $h_m$ is orthogonal to $Span\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ and $r_m \in Span\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$. So, $||h_m|| \le a$ and  $1 \ge ||r_m||^2 = 1 - ||h_m||^2 \ge 1 - a^2$. Then $||w_m - w_n||^2 = ||r_m - r_n||^2 + ||h_m - h_n||^2 \le ||r_m - r_n||^2 + 4a^2 < ||r_m - r_n||^2  + \alpha^2_0$. Now we observe that $r_m$ is a bounded sequence in finite dimensional space and therefore value $||r_m - r_n||$ can be made arbitrarily small for $m \ne n$; $m,n > m_k$ and this contradicts with assumption that $||w_n - w_m|| > \alpha_0$ for all $m \ne n$.

Comment: Thank you so much!